# Decompressing file as uploading to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have data that I want to upload to HDFS

data folder is multi-layer, but innermost dir only contains multiple .gz files.

folder is about 250 GB compressed, and I don't know how many gz files are in there.

I want to upload this to HDFS but they should be decompressed.

Is there a way that I can achieve this with single `hadoop fs -put` command?
or is writing a script file decompressing one by one and uploading to hdfs the only way?

Comment: GZ files are supported by most Hadoop processes. They just aren't splittable. `-put` cannot extract, though

Comment: yes, that is my concern. putting gz directly on hdfs is not an issue. The fact that they should be decompressed when it is on hdfs is.

Comment: You could look into adding Apache Nifi and using its ExtractFile processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that only with a script file, by uncompressing each file. But you can reduce the script with a pipe, something like this:

```
for file in $( ls ); do
    echo Uncompressing and putting $file
    gunzip -c $file | hdfs dfs -put - "/hdfs-dir/$file.txt"
done
```

Comment: ya I just created script as well